# How can two mermaids (one paralyzed), escape underwater prison built to capture their kind? Also, what kind of prison will that be?

Tags: underwater, merfolk, prison, criminal-underworld, escape

The situation on which my question is based, two mermaids are imprisoned in an underwater prison unit. This city is on top of a plateau. Hence, mers mostly move horizontally like humans and often vertically, depending on the landscape. 
They can also harness the power of the ocean to perform elementary magic.

Now, one of the mermaid is imprisoned as she couldn't provide a valid identification after immigrating to this place. *For reasons relevant to the plot,*  she is in excruciating pain and paralyzed from the waist down, covered in blood. She cannot swim at all. Someone has to carry her to escape. The other mermaid is physically healthy and is imprisoned for not paying her taxes. She has been in jail a couple times before and is quite familiar with the place. In what unit of the prison, is it possible for these two types of criminals to be imprisoned together?

Keeping in mind the water pressure, current flow, types of materials that can be used,  what kind of prison should be built underwater for merpeople who have elementary magic powers (mostly water magic) and can move in 3 dimensions? How can a half paralyzed and an able bodied mermaid escape this kind of prison built to trap their kind?

Comment: Two question, one of which is [plot related](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) and thus outside the range of Q-s the WB can [help](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help). The in-scope q is "what kind of prisons have to be built to house first degree notorious criminals with elemental magic powers". The out-of-scope q is "how can these three beings make an escape?"

Comment: this is under sea right ? i think the water pressure probably bleed her more quickly, though i can imagine it trigger shark to wreak havoc in there giving chance for their escape, but this depend on the depth though.....

Comment: It's a royal prison, they don't let prisoners die just because they are wounded. They try to make an example of them, keeping them alive as long as possible.

Comment: "two separate legs with webbed feet [...] using which they glide through water horizontally as we humans walk on land" — Have you actually *tried* doing that? It's *incredibly* inefficient compared to just swimming like, oh, *almost any marine animal* (not just fish, but penguins, seals, whales, etc.). It's completely impractical unless they're walking *on* something, and for that case, you want to *minimize* flow resistance. *If* they have legs, they'll be narrow like the legs of a crab. At best, they'll swim like scuba divers. Walking upright, like humans on land, is just silly.

Answer (score 3):

**The best escape is through the front door.**

He is a prince right, Money should not be a problem, So here is how he does this.

A disguise of an old uncle of the immigrant and some forged documents. Present those to the warden, court, or anyone relevant and tell them she has been unlawfully imprisoned, a few bribes at correct points should get her out within 48 hours.

Another disguise of second mermaid's wannabe boyfriend, who is in love with her, pays her taxes and fine and bail papers. Again bribes if needed. Should get her out even before the immigrant.

I know not much adventurous and thrilling way to do a prison escape, but a prince should be smart.

And about the type of prison, any prison would do for this type of escape.

**For minor crimes**, just a [shark cage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shark_cage_diving) like thing would do.
**For major crimes**, an underwater [Gibbeting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbeting)  would be cool. Both made with magic resistance steel, harder than titanium and buoyant, tied to the ocean floor.

Answer (score 2):

**How to contain mermaids**

Put bars over all windows, and reinforce ceilings.

**how to stop elemental magic**

Place counter spell artifacts placed every 30 meters

**how to escape**

Prince handles an inspection of the prison, picks up the counter spell artifact and moves it so the tax evader is out of range, the tax evader then elemental magics their way out (probably breaking prison bars) and pulls MC with her.

Answer (score 2):

The prince is after the hurt one.  He shows up as the prince.  The jailers know who he is.  He has some involvement with this prison since he knows every detail.  He is very serious.

The jailers do not know who this dying immigrant mermaid is.   The prince tells them "We screwed up, bad.  This girl is important in her own country and we have her dying in our jail."  The jailers are happy to point out that the error was not on their part and are very ready not to take the fall for this error.  They are delighted to hand her over.

The prince tells them "Keep this quiet and maybe we can fix things."  The jailers are very ready to do that too.

The prince realizes she cannot go on her own.  It is unseemly for a prince to carry a person, especially of the opposite sex and covered with blood.  The tax evader looks strong.  He points at her.  "You. Help me with her."